# How do I get this to not copy the last disk added to the system, or just pull the entire disk that the OS resides on?

Tags: batch-file

Currently for example we have 4 disks Disk 0, 1, 2, 3. How do I exclude Disk 3 as it is the last disk added? I get it to cycle through the disks and image them all but I need to exclude the last disk added to the system or just image the entire Disk that the OS resides on.

```
@echo Test collection
title test.bat %1 %2 %3
cls
For /F "Tokens=2" %%G In ('"Echo List Disk | "%__AppDir__%diskpart.exe" 2> 
NUL | "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" /RC:"^Disk [0-9]* ""') do (


pushd  %1:\FTK_Imager-CLI\

echo %date% %time% - Raw-Image\%computername%-drive%%G >> 
%2:\%computername%\%computername%-log.txt

mkdir %2:\%computername%\Raw-Image\%computername%-drive%%G\

%1:\FTK_Imager-CLI\ftkimager.exe \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE%%G %2:\%computername%\Raw- 
Image\%computername%-drive%%G\%computername%-drive%%G --e01 --frag 2G -- 
compress 6 --case-number TBD --evidence-number %computername%-drive%%G -- 
description %computername%-drive%%G --examiner TBD --notes none
echo[ >> %2:\%computername%\%computername%-log.txt

popd
)
echo Finished
```

Comment: when you use `wmic` the disk indexing is in reverse.. i.e `3`,`2`,`1` so you could use `skip=2` to skip the header and the last added drive: `for /f "skip=2 tokens=1" %%i in ('wmic diskdrive get index^, InterfaceType') do @echo %%i`

Comment: So after reading a few dozen posts and the for /? I believe that the best way to do this is by using the 9th token. If the 9th token is not null then I want to copy that drive. How would I do that @Gerhard. I am trying to wrap my head around it but I am far from a pro here. I appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon your statement, "just image the entire Disk that the OS resides on", and ignoring the fact you appear to be passing three arguments, but using only two, and, taking account that you've used invalid new lines in your code, perhaps this may assist you.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Title %~nx0 %1 %2 %3
ClS
Echo Test Collection
Set "DiskIndex="
For /F Delims^= %%G In ('^""%__APPDIR__%wbem\WMIC.exe" LogicalDisk Where "DeviceID='%SystemDrive%'" Assoc:List /ResultClass:Win32_DiskPartition^|"%__APPDIR__%find.exe" "DiskIndex=" 2^>NUL^"')Do Set "%%G"
If Not Defined DiskIndex GoTo :EOF
(Echo %DATE% %TIME% - Raw-Image\%COMPUTERNAME%-drive%DiskIndex%)>>"%~2:\%COMPUTERNAME%\%COMPUTERNAME%-log.txt"
MD "%~2:\%COMPUTERNAME%\Raw-Image\%COMPUTERNAME%-drive%DiskIndex%"
"%~1:\FTK_Imager-CLI\ftkimager.exe" \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE%DiskIndex% "%~2:\%COMPUTERNAME%\Raw-Image\%COMPUTERNAME%-drive%DiskIndex%" --e01 --frag 2G --compress 6 --case-number TBD --evidence-number "%COMPUTERNAME%-drive%DiskIndex%" --description "%COMPUTERNAME%-drive%DiskIndex%" --examiner TBD --notes "none"
(Echo=)>>"%~2:\%COMPUTERNAME%\%COMPUTERNAME%-log.txt"
Echo Finished
```

*Please note however, missing from this example is some code to ensure that the input arguments are passed, are valid, and exist. You should incorporate them as this is clearly for production use. Also note that I have used [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic), instead of [diskpart](/questions/tagged/diskpart), which I do not believe is necessary for this task. It may also be worth mentioning that you may need to ensure that your software will be able to image the in use drive, if this is running on the PC to be imaged.*

If you want "to exclude the last disk added to the system", you may be able to use `"%~1:\FTK_Imager-CLI\ftkimager.exe" --list-drives` within a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop), and just omit the last listed result, *(this would be preferable to using [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic))*. As questions should be limited to one per post, I'm not however going to include an example using that method, on this occasion.